# PHP File Encyrpted

Tags: php, encryption

I dont know how or what this PHP file is doing but its encyrpted and I need to decyrpt it. I heard its base64 or something but Its really hard. Code..

(code removed)

Dont ask what it is, But I need to find out what it is doing.

Thanks

Comment: where did u get this code?  is it top secret information?

Comment: Your site has probably been infected.  Remove the code and find your SQL injection hole.

Comment: Please don't post potentially-malicious code without providing some context showing that you have a serious question, especially not as a first-time user. Posts like this show up all the time, either trying to trick someone careless into actually running it, or containing some "Ha ha! Gotcha" message. Voting to close

Comment: Change the outer 'eval' function call into 'print', and it'll spit out the decoded code. But generally this technique is used to hide malicious code, so you're either pranking SO, or got hacked.

Comment: @Pekka: This is what http://ideone.com is for.

Comment: ... Its not for my website, Its someone telling to me to run it and I have ran it i am not an idiot and it ant malicious. I can prove it in any means possible.

Comment: Where have I [seen this before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eval+gzinflate+%22base64_decode%22)?

Comment: @Bob: If someone gave you a blob and told you to eat it, would you? **Never run untrusted code**!

Comment: @Bob: How can you prove it's not malicious?

Comment: The code posted in the question came from: http://system.opencp.org/runner.phps, which has an invalid SSL certificate.  OpenCP, seems to be a private Club Penguin server.

Answer (score 4):

It executes the (presumably evil) PHP code at `https://system.opencp.org/source.txt`.
This site has an invalid SSL certificate; I didn't look at the file.

Comment: @Marc: There is nothing intrinsically wrong with that URL - it's server-side code, not a browser exploit.

Comment: Looked more like some chat system than malware.

Comment: The code posted in the question came from: https://system.opencp.org/runner.phps, which also has an invalid SSL certificate.

Comment: OpenCP, seems to be a private Club Penguin server.